# After IntelliJ 2019.1.3 update, I Could not Push My Code To Remote Repository

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I updated IntelliJ to 2019.1.3

I can commit my code, but I cannot push my code to a remote repository. I get an authentication error. When I paste my password multiple times, sometimes it accepts my password and pushes the code to the remote repository and sometimes it does not.

When intellij accepts my password and I checked the "remember box", Intellij asks password for the next time.

By the way, when I open terminal in Intellij and run `git push`, Intellij does not ask for the password and push my code without any complains.

I re-install intellij, Invalided cache, I  updated git program. No solution. Is there any advice?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 10 @Peter

Comment: There is no 2019.3 version. Even 2019.2 is not released yet. So, what version are you on? 2019.1.3? What version were you using previously? In fact, logs are needed to investigate this, so probably the best course of action is submitting a ticket to JetBrains support

Comment: you are right. my mistake. It is 2019.1.3 sorry. I will change it. By the way I upgraded from 2019.1.2. @DmitriySmirnov

Comment: There were no any changes between 2019.1.2 and 2019.1.3 that affect git authentication. Please check IDE logs for errors.

Answer (score 0):

As a wild guess, since it works sometimes, and sometimes not, the issue might be related to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-212274. Logs are needed to check this.

> By the way, when I open terminal in Intellij and run git push, Intellij does not ask for the password and push my code without any complains.

IntelliJ terminal is just an embeded system terminal. IntelliJ is not involved in git operations executed via terminal. So this test just proves that git itslef wotks and the issue is on IntelliJ side.

Comment: When IntelliJ does not ask for password. I got this error message. "Enumerating objects: 54, done. Delta compression using up to 8 threads Total 32 (delta 11), reused 0 (delta 0) the remote end hung up unexpectedly the remote end hung up unexpectedly RPC failed; HTTP 401 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 401" @DmitriySmirnov

Comment: returned error: 401 means unauthorized. This error is likely the result of failed authentication prompt and is rather expected. It is not the reason for prompt failure and does not clarify it. IDE logs should nave more details. Consider submitting a ticket to Jetbrains support to review logs.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before, what you have to do is to go to github. I will show all the steps:

Step 1: Go to your github

Step 2: Go to settings

Step 3: Go to to the developer setting:

[image]

Step 3: Go to personal tokens:

[image]

Step 4: Now if you have a private repository go to the "Fine-grained personal access tokens Beta" and create a token from there. Moreover, take in the consideration the permission than you want to give with that token:

[image]

You can add permissions for just the public repositories, which is not helpful if you have a private repository.

Step 5: Go back to your android studio or any intellij IDE and past that token instead of password